# Objective C - Adding Constraints to make app Viewable in iPad from iPhone 5 and 6

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, size-classes

I'm trying to make my app viewable in iPhone 5, 6, and iPad. I've been successful in adding constraints in iPhone 5 and 6  but not in iPad.

Here is the image:

[image]

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You may have given height only related to iPhones, you can customize your constraints related to iPad and iPhone. Double click on any constraint and customize it with **Compact Width** **Compact Height** for your iPhones and the first constant will display your constraints for iPad.. [image]